# Can the dnx/dotnetcore package cache location be changed

Tags: .net, dnx, dnu, dnx50

I have a machine where the C:\ drive is running out of space and I'd like to change the location where my DNX/DOTNET packages are installed to a location under my D:\ drive.

Is the package cache location configurable?

*NOTE: I don't have the flexibility to change my profile location to a different drive.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `NUGET_PACKAGES` environment variable and set it to a path you prefer.

Specifically, open up System Properties, create a user environment variables called `NUGET_PACKAGES`, and set it to a path of your choosing.

[image]

You will need to restart Visual Studio and any other programs for them to see the updated environment variable.

This works with Nuget 3.3 / .NET Core RC1.